# How to use Gibbs sampler to simulate normal-normal hierarchical models?

Tags: bayesian, simulation, metropolis-hastings, gibbs

This is related to Gelman's BDA 3rd Edition Chapter 11, Sec 3. The book says the following.

"The Gibbs sampler is the simplest of the Markov chain simulation algorithms, and it is our first choice for conditionally conjugate models, where we can directly sample for each conditional posterior distributions. For example, we could use Gibbs sampler for normal-normal hierarchical models in Chapter 5."

I am a bit confused on where conjugate model assumption is applied. The book seems to imply that Metropolis-Hasting algorithm should be applied whenever the model is non-conjugate.

$Q:$ Suppose we consider the following hierarchical model. For $1\leq i\leq n$, $y_i\sim  N(\theta_i,\sigma^2),\theta_i\sim N(\mu,\tau^2)$ where $p(\mu,\tau)$ is proportional to 1 to get proper posterior. One can easily read off the posterior distributions of $p(\theta_i|\theta_{-i},\mu,\tau,\vec{y}),p(\mu|\theta,\tau,\vec{y})$ and $p(\tau|\mu,\theta,\vec{y})$ in this case where $\theta_{-i}$ is all $\theta$'s except $\theta_i$. I do not see why I need the help of conjugate family here as long as I can read off the distribution. Furthermore, $\mu,\tau$ are not in conjugate family and they happen to be given by normal and Gamma distributions. The conjugacy only applies to $\theta$ here. Why Gibbs sampler is preferred in conjugate family as compared to Metropolis-Hasting? For Metropolis-Hasting, I need a jumping distribution which one could just use normal distribution.

Comment: A flat prior is a limiting case of a conjugate prior.

Comment: The Gibbs sampler has a 100% acceptance rate, but M-H does not and typically needs some tuning of its parameters (e.g., those of the proposal distribution.)

Comment: @Xi'an I see. So in that case, they do form conjugate family then. How is Gibbs sampler preferred in in conjugate family case? The book indicates that Gibbs sampler is first preference in conjugate family case. All I could see is that whenever I can write down conditional posterior by hand, Gibbs sampler applies instead.

Comment: @jbowman Does this conjugate family business have anything to do with rejection rate here? I could not see it. M-H does have a rejection rate defined by ratios of ratios of posterior by jumping distribution. But why should I prefer Gibbs sampler?

Comment: a) it's easier to manage - the proposal distribution is handed to you and is exact, b) it's faster, as there are no rejections and a much shorter burnin, and c) it's simpler to program.

Comment: @jbowman I think those properties were referring to Gibbs sampler. I think Xi'an had answered the question in the answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/244902.